# Hide ssi directive in aspx (web forms) on IIS 10 but render it in response

Tags: asp.net, nginx, iis-10, ssi

I need hide ssi directive `<!--#include virtual="1.html"-->` in aspx page (web forms) on IIS 10 but render it in response for execute SSI on Nginx proxy.
How can i do this? Trying like this

```
<div>
<!--#include virtual="1.html"-->
</div>
```

but asp throws an syntax analyzer exception.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem like this:

`<!-- <asp: Literal runat = "server"> #include virtual = "1.html" </ asp: Literal> -->`

The element must be a server.